# ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on project ':app'

Tags: android

I've imported an existing project from this link https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok

After importing into the android studio I came across this error
ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on project ':app'

Here is the code with the error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

I've looked at all the similar questions and tried resolving by changing the implementation to compile then back again cause it didn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: remove apply plugin: 'maven'

Answer (score 0):

Did u update your Gradle plugin? Remove "apply plugin: 'maven'" from dependencies level and run build.